# how to add language support to android

Tags: android, kernel

i hope someone put me on the right direction with my problem

i want to work on supporting my language, specially the writing on android

we use Arabic characters with little modification ( like parsi, urdu etc)..

i was hoping android has fully supported Arabic , then i would make changes to work with my language. but even 2.2 dosn't support Arabic . it just show Arabic characters and it is not connected. 
 that is "عربية " is displayed "ع ر ب ي ة".

some individuals have made [Arabic](http://code.google.com/p/arabicandroid) support on CyanogenMod ROM's for some HTC phones, but they would not tell how they made it.
I'v got the android source code, i want to know where to start, where to make changes , what is the library that handle fonts , shaping engine etc ..

ps : android.com and other android related google groups are blocked in my country.

Comment: Cannot help too much... but, why don't you use a webproxy to reah android.com and its google groups?

Comment: i can't afford to mess with Great firewall  :D
plus it is smart enough to catch encrypted webproxies..

Comment: I think you can download CyanogenMod's sources at https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android, and (at least in version 7) it has right-to-left languages support, including Arabic shaping.

Comment: try out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android

Answer (score 1):

[Anymemo](http://anymemo.org/) is an open-source Android application that has support for Arabic.  You can easily check it out with git and take a look at how they solved it.

Comment: Anymemo use Arabic reshaper which is Application level solution, but can be used system wide . that is exactly what im doing now, thank.

Comment: @avar You should accept this answer now.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only about the font you can change the fonts of text you are using by adding the font file to /assets directory and use it on textViews and etc by adding

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "yourFont.ttf");
TextView text=new TextView("Text","this");
text.setTypeface(font);
```

But I am not sure that all the problem is about finding the right font.( I don't know if the languages you are talking about uses letters which combine with each other like Chinese, it would be harder to manage something like that though) 
But I believe you may find or create a better font which has less space around the letters so that the letters would look closer.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen references to modifying /system/fonts/Droid*.ttf by those looking to add an unsupported language.  Modifying that folder requires root access to the device.

I also read that the Android OS does support right-to-left languages such as Hebrew, Arabic and Hindi.  I don't know if it is able to stitch the characters together as you want, though.  I haven't done this myself.

Answer (score -1):

try the "google translate" which has a good support for languages.just download the jar and add it to your application and call its method to translate to any language.

Comment: The OP was asking on how to implement (properly) the display of languages with characters different to latin ones, and read from right to left.