# How support only single apk diffrent locale and languages in android

Tags: android

I am working on an android app. It supports multiple languages and locale. So, i need to develop different apks with different string.xml or I need to create only one apk for my application. Is there any disadvantage to create different apk for same application for different locale?

Comment: Obviously, it's much better to have only one apk. And android provides a clever mechanism for that: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add language support to android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022187/how-to-add-language-support-to-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create only one apk. Put the different strings inside as many folders as you need for your languages. Example:

- values

  - ...
  - strings.xml (default strings)
  - ...
- values-es

  - strings.xml (spanish strings)
  - arrays.xml (spanish arrays)
- values-en

  - strings.xml (english strings)
  - arrays.xml (english arrays)

Comment: thanx but  how i check my app work propery on diffrent locale and language any way to make emulator locale specific

Comment: i have only tried in real devices, but changing language inside settings >> Language & input should do the trick =)

Comment: In Real Device how i change locale and language to check the Application is work or not thanx.....

Comment: Using the same method. You can adjust the language used in your device in Settings >> Language & Input. Close your application, change the language used by your device and restart your application.